# What is different from Config and Backing Service?

Tags: spring, properties

I am learning the 12 factor rule. I cannot get my head around the difference between storing configuration into environment and Backing service. Also how would u store properties into "Environment"?

Ex: I have a configuration for connection to orcale sql, with jdbc.

Should I consider it as a config. or a backing service; when I provide the details and attach it to my cloud foundry application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backing service means your code should be agnostic to what Database, Binary Storage, etc service you're using:

```
// BAD:
let user = createNewUser();  // assuming it will create a new user to be saved to DB
oracleDatabase.save(user);

// GOOD:
let user = createNewUser();  // assuming it will create a new user to be saved to DB
database.save(user);
```

In other words, there should be a high level abstraction so that your app interact with an adapter (like a Database Adapter), rather than a low level component (such as an Oracle Database component).

As far as configuration goes, it means you should store your configuration in a place where in order to change it, you don't need to recompile/redeploy/etc. For instance:

Say you have a web app, and a class like this:

```
 class Constants {
     const DB_HOST = "72.234.45.223";
     const DB_USER = "admin";
     ...
     const MAIL_DRIVER = "smtp";
 }
```

But your IT department move the database to a different server.  Or you want to run your app in your development machine. In both cases you'd have to recompile and redeploy the application.  In the development machine example, you'd have to change back the values before committing your changes to the version control system.

Now, if you store it in a configuration file, or in the environment variables, you wouldn't have to recompile or redeploy. Instead, the app will read these values in runtime and you'd only need to modify the configuration file. Also, since the configuration file **should not be in version control**, you won't have to worry about committing a change to the main repository that would alter these values and break the whole production build.

You might want to check out **dotenv** ([ruby](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv), [php](https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv), [python](https://github.com/jpadilla/django-dotenv), and maybe there are for other languages) for an easy way to to this with environment variables.

Comment: Thank you for clarifiying. So what if I have some basic configs for thyme leaf.  in my application.properites file spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html. Would I have to store these in the environment variable also? and leave app.properties/yml blank?

Comment: I'm not familiarized with that particular framework/tech stack. However the concepts apply for everything. Just think of it this way:  if you put your API key, database credentials, etc in those files;  then commit to the main repo;  then hire a 3rd party consultant to work on that project;  would the API keys, credentials, etc  be compromised?  If so, they don't belong in that file, but in the environment.

Comment: I understood that credentials should be stored in the environments. But what about general configs that has nothing to do with credentials. Should they also be in the environment or leaving in the properties file would be fine.

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco  While I agree the configurations should not be stored in the *same* repository with the code, I highly disagree with them not being under *some sort* of version control: how do you reliably restore or roll them back (and fast!) when something bad happens?

Comment: @DanCornilescu that's a nice topic you mention there. I haven't read any articles describing this subject, but it sounds interesting. However, I believe the 12factor app talks specifically about storing config on the environment, regardless if it is loaded into environment from _another_ repository or manually set up by the system administrator